# How to time sync two systems in same network?

Tags: ntp

I want my laptop to derive it's clock time from another system which is located  in another building.Both the systems use Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use NTP.  To install, if not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Once done, you can do:

```
ntpdate <machine_IP_address>
```

example: `ntpdate 192.168.1.9`

For more info, see [Time Synchronisation with NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html)